# Closing-Event of window in Pyglet

Tags: python, pyglet

After closing Pyglet by the "X" of the window, I assume the Event "on_close" would be triggered, but it doesn't seems so. What do I do wrong?

```
window = pyglet.window.Window(fullscreen=False)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    sprite.draw()
    label.draw()

def on_close():
    print("I'm closing now") #<- this never happens
```

Complete Script here (Line 175):
https://github.com/VirToReal/py-slideshow/blob/master/slideshow.py

Comment: add `window.close()` statement in `on_close()` function.

Comment: the problem is, the function "on_close" never gets called, I updated the link for the full application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window(fullscreen=False)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    window.flip()

@window.event
def on_close():
    print("I'm closing now") #<- this never happens

pyglet.app.run()
```

You've got two problems, one - you're missing `pyglet.app.run()` or any form of event dispatching in your application.

The other problem is that you didn't use a [decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators) for the `on_close()` function.
The previously declared decorator is only for that function, that is `on_draw()`.

Some other side notes:
You didn't clear the window and some times `flip()` needs to be called, might be good to remember.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't copied the whole text. But the additional @window.event did the trick! Thanks alot!

Comment: @BennyH. No worries, glad it's working :) Happy coding!